# Cambiar color de fondo de un texto dependiendo de las coincidencias encontradas

Tags: javascript

Tengo un bucle `for in` que compara los caracteres de una variable string llamada `revelar` obtenida de un input con una variable llamada `palabraOculta`
La cuestión es que necesito resaltar con un color `verde` el texto en el html cuando `revelar` sea igual a `palabraOculta` `amarillo` cuando `revelar` contenga uno o más caracteres iguales a `palabraOculta` y `gris` cuando no haya coincidencias.
El problema es que cuando por ejemplo `revelar="asada"` y `palabraOculta="algas"` la respuesta que obtengo es que los 3 caracteres `a` se pintan en dos colores. `verde y amarillo` Necesito que solo se pinte la cantidad existente en `palabraOculta`

```js
for(let i in palabraOculta){
    const SPAN = document.createElement("span");
    if(revelar[i] === palabraOculta[i]){
        SPAN.innerHTML = revelar[i];
        SPAN.style.backgroundColor = "green";
    }else if(palabraOculta.includes(revelar[I])){
        SPAN.innerHTML = revelar[i];
        SPAN.style.backgroundColor = "yellow";
    }else{
        SPAN.innerHTML = revelar[i];
        SPAN.style.backgroundColor = "grey";
    }
}
```

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! en el caso que planteas, de que color va cada letra?

Comment: Favor [edit] y agregar un ejemplo más funcional, donde existan valores para `palabraOculta` y `revelar`, así como el HTML necesario